# Unexpected Parameter when grabbing a tweet reply

Tags: python, tweepy

i want to ask, is there a reason why i can't check my twitter replies with this code? i tried running it, and it says that `Unexpected parameter: timeout`. I've already made my twitter developer project to read and write, it still doesn't work. I need this code to get the account that replied to my tweet. Here is the code that i use

```
import tweepy
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
twitter_auth_keys = {
    "consumer_key"        : w,
    "consumer_secret"     : x,
    "access_token"        : y,
    "access_token_secret" : z
}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
        )
auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
        )
api = tweepy.API(auth)

name = u
tweet_id = v
    
replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q='to:'+name, result_type='recent', timeout=999999).items(1000):
        if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
            if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==tweet_id):
                replies.append(tweet)

replies
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is quite simply because there is no parameter called `timeout` in the `search_tweets` function of tweepy.

`search_tweets` doc:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

If you go down to the parameters section, you will see that the other parameters such as `q` and `result_type` are there, but not `timeout`. So the solution is to remove the `timeout=999999` parameter from your code.

Comment: When i tried to run it, it doesn't seem to output the replies, is there a reason why?

Comment: Are there any errors that come up at any point? Its best if you debug your code and see where the output gets dropped.

Comment: Is there a possibility if the replies on my tweet shows that `the tweet may contain offensive content`, it won't give the output a return?

Comment: That should not be the case. If it was, then there should be a parameter in the `search_tweets` function that allows those tweets, which I can't see.

Comment: I tried doing it with a different tweet it seems to work, not fully but it outputs a tweet. i don't know why it won't output the replies on my tweet @M_B

Comment: and also can you explain what is the function of q in the parameter? is it for searching a keyword?

Comment: Is it possible that it needs to use this doc now https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all#tab1?

Comment: Yes, you need to use that doc since it details the `search_tweets` function. If you want to know about what the `q` parameter, check https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/integrate/build-a-query